# Python code acting differently than when run in terminal

Tags: python, subprocess, mpi

When I pass my mpirun command through terminal, the normal (and expected) outcome is an output file with a bunch of data in it.

However when I pass the code through my python script, all of the output files that are expected are created, however they contain no data. Is there any global explanation for this? I have tried the code many different ways, using both os.system and subprocess. I have also tried running the code in the background as well as just running. And I have also tried just having the program spit out the data vs. saving it to the output file, and all give the same result.

Here is the code:

```
os.system("mpirun -np 4 /home/mike/bin/Linux-ifort_XE_openmpi-1.6_emt64/v2_0_1/Pcrystal > mgo.out")
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get that behavior is if mpirun is not being successfully run.

For instance if, from the command line, I run

```
not_actually_a_command > myFile.txt
```

myFile.txt will be created, but will be empty (the "command not found" message is printed to stderr so won't be caught by ">").

Try using the fully resolved path to mpirun

There doesn't seem to be something inherently wrong with your approach. When I do

```
os.system("echo hello, world >hello.txt")
```

it ends up with "hello, world" in it, so if you get your command to run it should work for you.

Comment: I agree with you, however the command does work. If I copy the mpirun command directly into terminal, it ends up working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with providing a complete path

```
os.system("/complete/path/to/mpirun
```

and print the result, print(os.system...etc.),
and post the error so we know what is wrong.
When using the subprocess module it may require a "shell=True"

Comment: I did this, it returns 0, indicating everything should be working.